# Metro ui css Dialog with Custom Buttons and Title

Tags: css, microsoft-metro

I've a div with id `PopUpDiv` and following code only show dialog which is not so pleasant. I want to Show different buttons in that dialogs, Save and Cancel button in footer and title in that Header.

```
function showDialog(id){
                    var dialog = $(id).data('dialog');
                    dialog.open();
                }
```

I have tried this one . But it's not working as well

```
$.Dialog({
    shadow: true,
    overlay: false,
    icon: '',
    title: 'Title',
    width: 500,
    padding: 10,
    content: 'Window content here',
    draggable: true,
    sysButtons: {
        btnMin: true,
        btnMax: true,
        btnClose: true
    },
    sysBtnCloseClick: function (e) {
                },
    sysBtnMinClick: function (e) {
               },
    sysBtnMaxClick: function (e) {
               }
})
```

Comment: Probably your post should be made pleasant first :)

Comment: I have added all References but still it shows error " $.Dialog is not a function"